# How to override the PhoneAccentBrush in WindowsPhone?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7.1

Basically PhoneAccentBrush comes with the SelectedTheme accent color from Phone. But i need always BlueAccentBrush for specific xaml file in the WindowsPhone application.

Actually my requirement is, When the ListPicker is in FullMode.. The SelectedItem color in the Popup depends upon the PhoneAccentBrush... If i set the Phone theme as Red.. then SelectedItem color in the Popup will be red.. But i dont like this.. I want always BlueAccentBrush for the SelectedItem in the Popup..

So can anyone help me to override the PhoneAccentBrush in the xaml file..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add ListPicker as below,

```
<StackPanel x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0" >     
<toolkit:ListPicker ListPickerMode="Full">
<toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="Item1"/>
<toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="Item1"/>
<toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="Item2"/>
<toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="Item3"/>
<toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="Item4"/>
</toolkit:ListPicker>
</StackPanel>
```

To override the ListPicker Selected  Item Color

```
<ResourceDictionary
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <Color x:Key="PhoneAccentColor">Blue</Color>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PhoneAccentBrush" Color="{StaticResource PhoneAccentColor}"/>
    <Style x:Key="PhoneTextAccentStyle" TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource PhoneTextBlockBase}">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

For more Details refer the below sample: http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/upload/articles/MangoCustomApplicationTheme%20_1_2_3.zip

Answer (score 1):

You can't override PhoneAccentBrush. It's a "system" resource. But you can change the way the `ListPicker` behaves. See http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/customizing-listpicker-for-wp7-part1 for a series of articles that show how.