# WPF Change focused TextBox background color

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox, mahapps.metro

*Note: I'm using MahApps.Metro.*

So what I wanted is to create a global style which affects all TextBoxes in the application. Style should on Focus (whether it's a mouse, keyboard, whatever) change the background of the focused TextBox.

My problem is similar to 
[Change the focused border color of a Wpf textbox when it GotFocus()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42013899/change-the-focused-border-color-of-a-wpf-textbox-when-it-gotfocus)

I still suck with styles and templates. This is the code they used.

```
    <Style
    BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}"
    TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Border
                    x:Name="border"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <ScrollViewer
                        x:Name="PART_ContentHost"
                        Focusable="false"
                        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Opacity" Value="0.56" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF7EB4EA" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Yellow" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

How do I write a control template similar to this one that changes the Background, instead of Border?
Since I'm using Metro, I have to extend base TextBox- otherwise I lose everything pre-configured.

I also noticed that using the template above moved my pointer a bit up and also it shortened its height. It's probably overriding the pointer settings too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, if you only need to change the background, then you don't need to create a template. You can achieve the same result with a simple style.
Here is the markup:

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroTextBox}">
     <Style.Triggers>
         <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
             <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
         </Trigger>
     </Style.Triggers>
 </Style>
```

`BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroTextBox}"` this part indicates that we are extending the TextBox style from Mahapps (you can find the resource name of the control to extend by just looking in the code, for example here is their TextBox style - https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/c26b33d114aec64d98afd4f729b28838583d8ed9/src/MahApps.Metro/MahApps.Metro/Styles/Controls.TextBox.xaml#L12).

Hope this will help.

Comment: Yep, this was the solution. And it was also my initial idea, but I think I messed something up with BasedOn first time. Thanks a lot for the additional info too :)