# How to change border color using triggers in WPF?

Tags: wpf, textbox, border

I need to change border color of one text box when mouse hover him, but with solution i write it does not work. Is there mistake in my code?
Background color changes, but border no.

Code below is my idea.

```
 <Style x:Key="BorderColor" TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Normal"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="TextBox.IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
```

Comment: The `ControlTemplate` probably doesn't use the `BorderBrush`.

Comment: I remember that there was an issue with TextBoxes and borders. Try to set the Border thickness to 1.1 or 0.9 and then apply the different colour. I think that was the solution.

Comment: @XAMlMAX Sorry, but no effect when i change thickness.

Comment: @l33t Which property use template?

Answer (score 2):

A quick and easy way to do this is to simply set the TextBox border thickness to 0 and encapsulate it in a parent border:

```
<Border BorderThickness="1" Width="500" Height="20" >
    <Border.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Border.Style>
    <TextBox x:Name="theTextBox" BorderThickness="0" />
</Border>
```

The "proper" way to do this is to [template the entire control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42013899/change-the-focused-border-color-of-a-wpf-textbox-when-it-gotfocus):

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="false" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="Red"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Why is necessary to have that <Border> and <ScrollViewer> element?

Comment: Because that's what it is in the original TextBox template, and parts of the framework's TextBox code look for it for things like scrolling and selection behaviour etc.That's why you need to name it "PART_ContentHost", it's a kind of pointer to those bits of code that says "hey! this is the part of this control that you're looking for".

Comment: An easier way to do this in future is to just create a control (e.g. your TextBox) in XAML, place the cursor over it, go to the properties tab and find Misc -> Template. Now click on the little square to the right of it, select "Convert to new resource" and press Ok. VS will expand out a copy of the control's template....which is mostly the same as what I've posted above, plus some extra stuff...allowing you to now edit and override its internal properties and bindings.

Answer (score 0):

Color of button border is controlled by template triggers of a button via button (Templated Parent) properties. Since priority of such triggers is almost the top most, you need to redefine control template of a button.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence